# Computing window functions for multiple dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `sales` of consisting of user id's, products those users have purchased, and the date of purchase:

| date | user_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | apple |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | orange |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | apple |
| 2021-01-02 | 3 | apple |
| 2021-01-03 | 3 | orange |
| 2021-01-04 | 4 | apple |

If I wanted to see product counts based on every users' most recent purchase, I would do something like this:

```
WITH latest_sales AS (
SELECT
    date
    , user_id
    , product
    , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
FROM
    sales
)
SELECT
    product
    , count(1) AS count
FROM
    latest_sales
WHERE
    rn = 1
GROUP BY
    product
```

Producing:

| product | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |
| orange | 2 |

However, this will only produce results for my most recent date. If I looked at this on `2021-01-02`. The results would be:

| product | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |
| orange | 1 |

How could I code this so I could see counts of the most recent products purchased by user, but for multiple dates?

So the output would be something like this:

| date | product | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | apple | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | orange | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 | apple | 2 |
| 2021-01-02 | orange | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | apple | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | orange | 2 |
| 2021-01-04 | apple | 2 |
| 2021-01-04 | orange | 2 |

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Can I see data example ?

Comment: I have edited the post to flesh out the example more

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the window function `row_number()` with the `PARTITION BY user_id` clause is not relevant in your case because it only focusses on the user_id of the current row whereas you want a consolidate view with all the users.
I dont have a better idea than doing a self-join on table `sales` :

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s2.date, user_id)
       s2.date
     , product
  FROM  sales AS s1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM sales) AS s2
    ON s1.date <= s2.date
 ORDER BY s2.date, user_id, s1.date DESC
)
SELECT date, product, count(*)
  FROM list
 GROUP BY date, product
 ORDER BY date
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aAjWpYky)